# Regex needs to match alphanumeric string with min of one number look ahead only checks second postion

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have been trying to solve this problem for a bit now and have had to turn to asking you fine people.

I have found the following regex pattern many times and from what I have read it should work but doesn't actually seem to work

```
\b(?=.\d)(?i)[a-z\d]{3,}\b
```

The problem with it is that if there is a letter at the second position of the string it fails even if there is a digit in the string.

So 60B15H passes like it should be but 6D15H fails which is not what I want

My requirements for the regex is that the string needs to be alphanumeric and contain at least one number in any position it can be all digits. It just cannot contain all letters or any special characters. It needs to be minimum of 3 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?i)\b(?=[a-z]*\d)[a-z\d]{3,}\b
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to tell the regex engine to check a digit after any letters. The `(?=[a-z]*\d)` lookahead is executed once after each leading word boundary `\b` and makes sure there is at least one digit after a sequence of letters.

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fi)%5cb(%3f%3d%5ba-z%5d*%5cd)%5ba-z%5cd%5d%7b3%2c%7d%5cb&i=+60B15H+passes+like+it+should+be+but+6D15H+fails&o=i)

Comment: Amazing that worked like a charm thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: I just want to note that the non-regex solution by Thomas will work differently from mine. The character classes strictly prohibit all letters and digits but ASCII ones. `IsLetter` is Unicode aware. Depending on the requirements, the choice is yours. To get the same with regex, you can use `\b(?=\p{L}*\d)[\p{L}\d]{3,}\b`.

Comment: Would that way be more efficient? The method I am currently work on and I am trying to improve its efficiency.

Comment: You should test and check what is more efficient. If you use the regex more than a hundred times, just declare it as a public static readonly field and use `RegexOptions.Compiled`. In that case, you won't have issues with performance. From my experience if you use regex wisely, there are never performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex when you can get the same with simple code:

```
public static bool isValid(string input)
{
    if(input.Length < 3 || input.All(c => char.IsLetter(c))) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return input.All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
}
```